Draw a probability tree like this
I am trying to draw a probability tree like this

I have never use tree in Mathematica, therefore, I  don't know how to start. How can I draw the above tree? I Know that, using Mathematica calculus the result automatically and exactly.

Do you just want to draw this graph or do you want a function that can generate such a graph from probabilities? If the latter, what are the input parameters?

I want to make a function that can generate.

So what is the form of your parameters?

Can you use 't'?

I mean, your input is a List or a Graph or something else? How can I know the name of each node and the corresponding probability?

I have never used tree, I don't understand your comment. You can free make the code.

Sart with KaryTree[15]...

A preliminary attempt. You can adjust based on this.
Clear["`*"]
makeGraph[vertex_, input_] := Module[{pos},
  pos = Position[input[[;; , 1]], vertex[[1]]];
  If[pos == {}, {vertex \[DirectedEdge] {Row@
       vertex[[2, ;; , 1]], {{"‎"}}
      }, {Row@vertex[[2, ;; , 1]], {{"‎"}}
      } \[DirectedEdge] {Times @@ 
       vertex[[2, ;; , 2]], {{StringReplace[
         ToString[vertex[[2, ;; , 2]]], {"{1, " -> "", 
          ", " -> "\[Cross]", "}" -> ""}]}}
      }},
   {makeGraph[{input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]], 
      Append[vertex[[2]], {input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]], 
        input[[pos[[1, 1]], 3]]}]}, input], 
    makeGraph[{OverBar[input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]]], 
      Append[vertex[[2]], {OverBar[input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]]], 
        1 - input[[pos[[1, 1]], 3]]}]}, input], 
    vertex \[DirectedEdge] {input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]], 
      Append[vertex[[2]], {input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]], 
        input[[pos[[1, 1]], 3]]}]}, 
    vertex \[DirectedEdge] {OverBar[input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]]], 
      Append[vertex[[2]], {OverBar[input[[pos[[1, 1]], 2]]], 
        1 - input[[pos[[1, 1]], 3]]}]}}
   ]
  ]
edge[a_] := Last@Last@Last@a
makeTree[input_] := 
 GraphTree[TreeGraph@Flatten[makeGraph[{"Start", {{"", 1}}}, input]], 
  TreeElementLabelFunction -> All -> First, 
  ParentEdgeLabelFunction -> All -> edge, TreeLayout -> Left]

input = {{"Start", "A", 0.2}, {"A", "B", 0.7}, {
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<A\>"\), \(_\)]\), "B", 0.15}};
makeTree[input]



Can you match the style, color, font, and sizes too please?

@user5601, your original image was very likely drawn with TikZ in $\TeX$ (see this example).  So if you want to have the exact same copy, why don't you just redraw it there instead of in Mathematica?

@Domen Maybe you want to talk with me. First, I think, Mathematica can draw it and calculate the results easyly. But, see the answer, I don't think so. Now, I can draw it and calculate the results automatically.

For something different:
a = {{0, 0.2, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.85, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   };
tm = a;
Table[tm[[j, j]] = 1, {j, 8, 11}];
dm = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, tm];
s = StationaryDistribution[dm];
p = Probability[x == #, x \[Distributed] s] & /@ {8, 9, 10, 11};
vl = {"Start", "A", "\[Not]A", "A\[And]B", "A\[And]\[Not]B", 
   "\[Not]A\[And]B", "\[Not]A\[And]B"};
pro = Style[Row[{"P{", #1, ")=", #2}], White, Bold] & @@@ 
   Thread[{vl[[-4 ;; -1]], p}];
wg = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[a /. 0 -> Infinity, 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Thread[Range[11] -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ (Join[vl, pro]))], 
  VertexSize -> 0.7, 
  VertexStyle -> {8 -> Red, 9 -> Red, 10 -> Red, 11 -> Red}]
Graph[dm]


